# Overstayed a visa in US, is it relevant to mention in a Schengen visa request?

Tags: visas, schengen, applications

One of my friends plans to visit Switzerland. He had overstayed a performing artists visa in US for a period of five years. While he went to the U.S. he had a permanent job in India. Now he is back in India and has been working in the same Engineering college for three years.

When he applies for the Schengen visa should he show all these details, even if it is not known that they will know. Will it lead to rejection?

Comment: Your friend should answer the questions on the form.  Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 8):

1. Never lie to immigration.
2. Never give information not asked.
3. Given that the Schengen transit visa can be "replaced" with a valid USA visa my educated guess is that the visa department of Schengen area countries must have access to the USA immigration databases. This is nothing more than a good guess, however, see next bullet point.
4. We are not Schengen visa officials and we do not even play one on TV. We do not know what factors do they take into consideration. Also, even if we would know we do not have the completed form so we can not answer your question.

Comment: (+1) I don't think they have access to anything. If they need to, they would just check the visa sticker (‘foil’ in US parlance, if I am not mistaken).

Comment: Canada has access to much of the American immigration databases. The FCC countries have limited access based on biometrics. The Schengen countries have absolutely no access.  The Schengen countries would NEVER sign an agreement with the USA because it would infringe on EU laws which are very strict with regards to retention of personal and biometric data. Usually, they don't retain any data beyond five years.

Answer (score 6):

As someone who travelled to the US and exited *after* my visa expired (but it was not as long as 5 years) - when I went to apply for my Schengen visa I noted the following:

1. The application doesn't ask if you have ever been to the US or been deported from the US. This is only asked on the US applications for a visa.
2. The officer at the embassy only asked the following (as it was my first time applying for Schengen):

   1. Have I ever been to Europe? - I answered this as "only in transit through the UK" - which is how I used to travel to the US.
   2. Have I ever been to the United States? - "Yes".

   That was it. Volunteering extra information is rarely a good idea.

You did not mention what type of visa your friend would be applying for (I was applying for a tourist visa to attend a conference). I do not know if this meant that my application was subject to fewer/different checks than say if I was applying for immigration or business or study - each application type requires a different set of supporting documents and evidences.

Comment: (+1) Not volunteering information is a golden rule.